# LookupError: from nltk.book import*

Tags: python, import, ipython, nltk, anaconda

In iPython console I typed `from nltk.book import` and I got several LookupErrors. Below shows the code I got.

```
*** Introductory Examples for the NLTK Book ***
Loading text1, ..., text9 and sent1, ..., sent9
Type the name of the text or sentence to view it.
Type: 'texts()' or 'sents()' to list the materials.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LookupError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-8446809acbd4> in <module>()
 ----> 1 from nltk.book import*

C:\Users\dell\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.3-py2.7.egg\nltk\book.py in <module>()
 20 print("Type: 'texts()' or 'sents()' to list the materials.")
 21 
---> 22 text1 = Text(gutenberg.words('melville-moby_dick.txt'))
 23 print("text1:", text1.name)
 24 

 C:\Users\dell\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.3-py2.7.egg\nltk\corpus\util.pyc in __getattr__(self, attr)
 97             raise AttributeError("LazyCorpusLoader object has no attribute '__bases__'")
 98 
 ---> 99         self.__load()
100         # This looks circular, but its not, since __load() changes our
101         # __class__ to something new:

 C:\Users\dell\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.0.3-py2.7.egg\nltk\corpus\util.pyc in __load(self)
 62             except LookupError as e:
 63                 try: root = nltk.data.find('corpora/%s' % zip_name)
 ---> 64                 except LookupError: raise e
 65 
 66         # Load the corpus.

 LookupError: 
 **********************************************************************
 Resource u'corpora/gutenberg' not found.  Please use the NLTK
 Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()
 Searched in:
- 'C:\\Users\\dell/nltk_data'
- 'C:\\nltk_data'
- 'D:\\nltk_data'
- 'E:\\nltk_data'
- 'C:\\Users\\dell\\Anaconda\\nltk_data'
- 'C:\\Users\\dell\\Anaconda\\lib\\nltk_data'
- 'C:\\Users\\dell\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
**********************************************************************

In [4]:
```

Can i know why I get these errors?

Comment: try using `nltk.dowwnload()` this would open a panel. From there in `Corpora` download `gutenberrg` book/corpora and try your command again

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Downloaded corpora that is mentioned in the error message. Will I needed the other corpora, which were not downloaded again later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your missing the `Gutenberg` corpora in `nltk.book`, hence the error.
The error is self descriptive.

You need to use `nltk.download()` to download the corpora.
[image]

Once the corpora is downloaded, re-run your command and check if the error comes up again. If it does, it would be for another corpora. Download that corpora too.

`from nltk.book import *` is not the preferred method, it is advisable to only import the corpora which you would be using in your code.
You could use `from nltk.corpus import gutenberg` instead.

See reference on [link](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html)

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded only the corpora that appears each time in the error. Will I need other corpora again as well?

Comment: It depends on your application and its usage. As you read through the nltk book you would realize that you won't require most of the corpus. Some of the Corpus which are required are `brown, treebank, wordnet, words, conll2000, conll2002, ieer, gutenberg`

Answer (score 3):

As the NLTK book says, the way to prepare for working with the book is to open up the `nltk.download()` pop-up, turn to the tab "Collections", and download the "Book" collection. Do it and you can read the rest of the book with no surprises.

Incidentally you can do the same from the python console, without the pop-ups, by executing `nltk.download("book")`

Answer (score 0):

Seems it searches for the data only at specific places (like mentioned in the error description). **Try copying the content of nltk into one of those directories (or create one) such as D:\nltk_data** 
**This solved the issue for me** (because the error would continue to show up even if the Guttenber was already downloaded since it did not find it at that place)

An excerpt from the error you get: (these are the directories among which you can choose where to place the nltk content so that it can be found)

- 'C:\Users\dell/nltk_data'
- 'C:\nltk_data'
- 'D:\nltk_data'
- 'E:\nltk_data'
- 'C:\Users\dell\Anaconda\nltk_data'
- 'C:\Users\dell\Anaconda\lib\nltk_data'
- 'C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data'

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should download the nltk_data package in the following directory:

[image: Screenshot 1]